# How is the java "this" keyword implemented?

Tags: java

How does the `this` pointer points to the object itself? Is it a java implementation or is it a compiler implementation?

Comment: Here is what we can get most about 'this'. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#251519

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are interested why not look at the byte code generated by the compiler

```
class HelloWorld
{
   private String hello = "Hello world!";

   private void printHello(){
   System.out.println (this.hello);
}

public static void main (String args[]){
  HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();
  hello.printHello();
}
```

}

Compile using

%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javac HelloWorld.java

Get bytecode using

javap -c HelloWorld

edit add output

```
enter code here

 HelloWorld();
 Code:
 0:   aload_0
 1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()
 4:   aload_0
 5:   ldc     #2; //String Hello world!
 7:   putfield        #3; //Field hello:Ljava/lang/String;
 10:  return

 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
 Code:
 0:   new     #6; //class HelloWorld
 3:   dup
 4:   invokespecial   #7; //Method "<init>":()V
 7:   astore_1
 8:   aload_1
 9:   invokespecial   #8; //Method printHello:()V
12:  return
```

}

Answer (score 8):

In the JVM bytecode, *local variable 0* (basically register 0) points to the current object when a method is invoked. The compiler simply uses `this` as an alias for local variable 0.

So I guess the answer is that the compiler implements `this`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a philosophical question.  I am not sure that a Java implementation is.

`this` is defined in the JLS and is a keyword in Java and the compile has to comply with that standard.  When you have a method like

```
object.method(args)
```

what is actually called in byte code is a method which looks like

```
method(object, args);
```

where `this` is the first argument.

At the JVM level, the parameters don't have names and the JIT could optimise the argument away if its not actually used.

Comment: :) No Peter. Got bounced in the interview with the question. Thot of checking it out.

Comment: Sometimes you get poorly worded questions in interviews.  It can be a sign the interviewer doesn't know the answer either, and just wants to know what you say.

Comment: Unless the posting was going to involve you working on a JVM implementation, that's a terrible question!

Comment: Actually the question was asked from the perspective of how this would be implemented in the source  if I were to write t.

Comment: `this` is not implemented in source.  It is implemented for you.  Can you give example of what you mean?